# How to move data between iCloud accounts?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

For some reason when I first got my iPhone the iCloud was created under my mom's email. Now that she recently got an iPad all of my contacts, Photo Stream, internet favourites, etc are all on her iPad.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to get rid of all my info off her iPad that doesn't involve anything getting erased from my phone. Eventually we need to create two separate iClouds, but how would you go about doing that when all the info is on "her" iCloud account?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution for getting your contacts at the very least. This is what I did from one iPhone to another iPhone.

Login to the iCloud account associated with the device you are trying to retrieve this data from.

Once you are logged in click on the contacts tab in iCloud. In the bottom left hand corner you will see a "setting gear". Click this and then click select all.

Once all have been selected, click the "settings gear" and click export vcard. Save as contacts somewhere you will be able to easily locate like your desktop.

Log out of that account and log into the account you wish to transfer this data to. Once you are logged in to this account, click contacts and the "settings gear" in the left hand corner. Click import vcard, locate and select vcard imported from other account. You should now see your contacts transferred from one account to the next.

You will then need to click the "setting gear" again and click refresh contacts. Power off your device associated with the device you want contacts transferred and power back on.

Once everything is updated you should see your contacts on your new device.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: you can't move everything from one iCloud account to the other.

Oh, you can do parts of it, but it will be slow and frustrating and aggravating, and even after all of that you still might not get everything, so save yourself the aggravation and take the easy way out instead.

### The Easy Way

1. Create a new iCloud account for your mother. The easiest way to do this is to create her a free iCloud account at iCloud.com and then have her use that for her iCloud documents, contacts, calendar, etc. Once it is created, log into iCloud.com and set the email to forward to her regular email account.
2. Keep using the existing account for yourself.

### The Hard Way

If you are annoyed at the fact that your Apple ID is your mom's email address, (or if you think creating a new account is going to be a problem in the future) then you *can* change the existing Apple ID from one email address to another... usually. The full details are way longer than I can fit here, but I will refer you to Apple's support document HT5796: [Apple ID: Changing your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5621) which gives these introductory instructions:

- Sign out of all Apple features and services that you use with your current Apple ID.
- Make sure that the email address you want to use for your Apple ID meets these conditions:
- The email address is one that you use regularly, because it will be the primary email address for your Apple ID.
- The email address is not associated with any other Apple ID.
- The email address is not an iCloud email address, which is already an Apple ID. iCloud email addresses end with @icloud.com, @me.com, or @mac.com.

Be sure to also read Apple Support Document HT5621: [Apple ID: What to do after you change your Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5796).

Once you have changed the existing Apple ID account from her email address to yours, you will then need to create a new Apple ID for your mother. To do this go to https://appleid.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to peace:

1. Create a new iCloud Acc.
2. Open both iCould accounts on your laptop.
3. In the Departure account=> click on the contacts tab=> In the bottom left hand corner click on "Setting Gear" => click on "Export Vcard => save data on desire location
4. On the destination account =>click on the contacts tab=> In the bottom left hand corner click on "Setting Gear" => click on " Import Vcard" => all data transfer

Good luck :)

Answer (score -2):

You can transfer everything from one icloud account to another. Just set up both accounts on the same PC/MAC and copy and past emails / contact etc..
E.G. Select all emails in Inbox one old icloud account, CTRL+C.  Then Past into new empty inbox, CTRL+V. Repeat for contacts etc..  Then set up forwarder if neccessary from old account to new account.